# Javac can't find package referenced in classpath

Tags: java, compilation, classpath, javac

I'm trying to compile a project with javac in windows, but I'm getting a "*package x does not exist*" error.
Even if the jar file containing them is in the classpath.

Here is the command, I just added line returns to make it readable:

```
javac
  -d bin
  -sourcepath src
  -cp 
    .;
    lib/gson-2.5.jar;
    lib/jruby-complete-9.1.2.0.jar;
    lib/lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-windows.jar;
    lib/lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-linux.jar;
    lib/lwjgl-platform-2.9.3-natives-osx.jar;
    lib/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;
    lib/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar;
    lib/jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar;
    lib/lwjgl.jar;
    lib/lwjgl_util.jar;
    lib/jorbis-0.0.17.jar;
    lib/jinput-2.0.5.jar;
    lib/gdx-platform-1.9.2-natives-desktop.jar;
    lib/gdx-controllers-platform-1.9.2-natives-desktop.jar;
    lib/gdx-freetype-platform-1.9.2-natives-desktop.jar;
    lib/gdx-1.9.2.jar;lib/gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.2.jar;
    lib/gdx-controllers-1.9.2.jar;
    lib/gdx-controllers-desktop-1.9.2.jar;
    lib/gdx-freetype-1.9.2.jar;
    lib/jlayer-1.0.1-gdx.jar;
    lib/jutils-1.0.0.jar
  src/com/azias/awbe/Launcher.java
```

And here is the error message:

```
src\com\azias\awbe\Launcher.java:3: error: package com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
                                      ^
src\com\azias\awbe\Launcher.java:4: error: package com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
                                      ^
src\com\azias\awbe\Launcher.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
                ^
  symbol:   class LwjglApplicationConfiguration
  location: class Launcher
src\com\azias\awbe\Launcher.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
                LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class LwjglApplicationConfiguration
  location: class Launcher
src\com\azias\awbe\Launcher.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
                new LwjglApplication(new AdvanceWarsBootleg(), config);
                    ^
  symbol:   class LwjglApplication
  location: class Launcher
src\com\azias\awbe\AdvanceWarsBootleg.java:3: error: package com.badlogic.gdx does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
                       ^
src\com\azias\awbe\AdvanceWarsBootleg.java:4: error: package com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d does not exist
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
                                    ^
src\com\azias\awbe\AdvanceWarsBootleg.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
public class AdvanceWarsBootleg extends Game {
                                        ^
  symbol: class Game
src\com\azias\awbe\AdvanceWarsBootleg.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        public SpriteBatch batch;
               ^
  symbol:   class SpriteBatch
  location: class AdvanceWarsBootleg
src\com\azias\awbe\AdvanceWarsBootleg.java:9: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
src\com\azias\awbe\AdvanceWarsBootleg.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
src\com\azias\awbe\AdvanceWarsBootleg.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                super.render();
                ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class AdvanceWarsBootleg
12 errors
```

Comment: Can you provide the absolute path to your jar files. This is in windows right?

Comment: The project folder is in: "C:\Users\Azias\Eclipse\workspace_neon\LibGDX - Advance Wars Bootleg Edition".  Should i try to remove the spaces in the folder's name ?

Comment: what i meant is in the command can you provide the the full path instead of starting with lib. And you are sure that one of the jar has the package right?

Comment: I just tried with the absolute path and a ./ before and I still have the same error.  And the package is in the "gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.9.2.jar" file.

Comment: can you try verbose option "-verbose" it should give you some insight on what the compiler is doing

Comment: I posted it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4q9RBxCn)

Comment: Not sure why you are seeing error class paths are set properly...

Comment: I found the error, I typed "lib" instead of "libs" in the batch script.
I'm so sorry for wasting you time on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 6 or later, the classpath option supports wildcards. Note the following:

```
Use straight quotes (")
Use *, not *.jar
```

so you could simplify your javac statement:

```
javac
  -d bin
  -sourcepath src
  -cp ".;libs/*"
  src/com/azias/awbe/Launcher.java
```

Also depending on the platform the separator is `;` (windows) or `:` (unix).